# How do I use cookies with RCurl?

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I am trying to write an R package that accesses some data via a REST API. The API, however, doesn't use http authentication, but rather relies on cookies to keep credentials with the session.

Essentially, I'd like to replace the following two lines from a bash script with two R functions: One to perform the login, and store the session cookie, and the second to GET the data.

```
curl -X POST -c cookies.txt -d"username=xxx&password=yyy" http://api.my.url/login
curl         -b cookies.txt                               http://api.my.url/data
```

I'm clearly not understanding how RCurl works with curl options. My script as it stands has:

```
library(RCurl)
curl <- getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar='cookies.txt', curl=curl)
postForm("http://api.my.url/login", username='xxx', password='yyy', curl=curl)
getURL('http://api.my.url/data", curl=curl)
```

The final `getURL()` fails with a "Not logged in." message from the server, and after the `postForm()` no `cookies.txt` file exists.

Answer (score 20):

In general you don't need to create a cookie file, unless you want to study the cookies.

Given this, in real word, web servers use agent data, redirecting and hidden post data, but this should help:

```
library(RCurl)

#Set your browsing links 
loginurl = "http://api.my.url/login"
dataurl  = "http://api.my.url/data"

#Set user account data and agent
pars=list(
     username="xxx"
     password="yyy"
)
agent="Mozilla/5.0" #or whatever 

#Set RCurl pars
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar="cookies.txt",  useragent = agent, followlocation = TRUE, curl=curl)
#Also if you do not need to read the cookies. 
#curlSetOpt(  cookiejar="", useragent = agent, followlocation = TRUE, curl=curl)

#Post login form
html=postForm(loginurl, .params = pars, curl=curl)

#Go wherever you want
html=getURL(dataurl, curl=curl)

#Start parsing your page
matchref=gregexpr("... my regexp ...", html)

#... .... ...

#Clean up. This will also print the cookie file
rm(curl)
gc()
```

### Important

There can often be hidden post data, beyond username and password. To capture it you may want, e.g. in Chrome, to use `Developer tools` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>) -> `Network Tab`, in order to show the post field names and values.

Comment: You are a Genius! +n to this awesome solution

Answer (score 6):

My bad. Neal Richter pointed out to me http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/RCurlJSS.pdf - which better explains the difference between `cookiefile` and `cookiejar`. The sample script in the question actually *does* work. But it only writes the file to disk when it is no longer being used.