# RCurl sending cookie

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I need to send a simple cookie using RCurl.
The cookie is "AcceptDisclaimer=yes"
I tried doing this:

```
curl <- getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar='cookies.txt', curl=curl)
resultingWebPage <- postForm(website, x = result,  curl = curl)
```

cookies.txt contains AcceptDisclaimer=yes

However, RCurl doesn't seem to send the cookie !

Regards !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cookie = 'cookiefile.txt'   
curl  =  getCurlHandle ( cookiefile = cookie,
                         cookiejar = cookie,
                         useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en - US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
)

# code to do something with web page

rm(curl)
gc()
```

Use of `cookiefile` will load the cookie stored in the file.
Use of `cookiejar` will use a temporary cookie

calling `rm(curl)` and `gc()` will remove the curl session and  cause the cookie file to be written to disk.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I use cookies with RCurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388974/how-do-i-use-cookies-with-rcurl) which points to http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/RCurlJSS.pdf. Section 4.4 of that document details how cookies can be loaded. It uses the `cookiefile`, not `cookiejar`, option and the format of the file is more complicated than what you have.