# How to download article from WSJ with RCurl

Tags: r, web, text-mining

I am trying to use RCurl along with XML package to download and mine article from the WSJ (wall street journal). However, whenever i use getURL from RCurl, i do get the version of the article which is available for public viewer.

What i would like to be able to do is to download the full version of the article - as i am paying member. I imagine i have to pass the login credential, when i call the function getURL, however, i am not sure how to do so..

1. Is this information stored in cookies?
2. Do i need be "authenticated" - whatever the difference (in purpose maybe) is?

I would appreciate if someone could explain how do website such as WSJ, uses login-info to fetch data, and how can i tweak RCurl in order to take such information into account. A very simple example will go a long way in explaining the different concept of setting cookies (files, jar, ..) etc

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think `httr` can deal properly with cookies.

Comment: can you give a bit more info pls?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, authentication information is not stored in cookies. Instead, a "session cookie" is stored on your computer - and refers to authentication stored on the server. See the [Session management article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_cookie#Session_management) for a bit more information and pointers.

So basically you will need to create a cookie jar file for this site, login with curl (this can be painful, as WSJ doesn't use the standard form-based POST but instead relies on javascript), and then you'll be able to tell curl to re-use the cookie for the following requests on the articles. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451157/333599) to see how to do it in practice.

Comment: thank you for your reply, and sorry it took me a while to respond.. If WSJ doesn't use standard form-based POST (javascript as you said), would you mind explaining a bit further how can i accomplish the task at hand? An RCode (similar to the one in the example) would help me great, as i am not an expert when it comes to web (networking, protocol, ...) Thanks.

Comment: @Lalas I provided a link to an answer giving you the full code to perform exactly what I explained, how is that not enough?

Comment: I got confused by your comment regarding "the POST relying on javascript". Thanks again for the link.