# Internal Server Error in RCurl - Certificate Issue?

Tags: r, rcurl

I am trying to use RCurl to log in to the following site: https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login. I get following error: "Error: Internal Server Error". Is this a certificate issue? I have seen links to this [site](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) about certificates, but I'm not sure where to start in my case. Here's the code, which was based off an answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388974/how-do-i-use-cookies-with-rcurl). What do I need to do to solve the error? Thank you.

```
library(RCurl)

#Set your browsing links 
loginurl = "https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login"

#Set user account data and agent
pars=list(UserName="user_xxxx", Password="password_xxxx") #User name and password taken out
agent="Chrome/39.0" 

#Set RCurl parameters
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar="cookies.txt",  useragent = agent, followlocation = TRUE, 
       curl=curl, sslversion=3L, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)

#Post login form
html=postForm(loginurl, .params = pars, curl=curl)
```

Comment: To clarify, I get the internal server error when I use ssl.verifypeer = FALSE. When I set it to true, I get this error :Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: I'd recommend using httr because it will configure ssl correctly for you